# lampp can't run after update on centos 7

Tags: php, linux, apache

did anyone know why lampp stop(can't auto run on boot) after update and install rpm-gpg-key-centos-7? normally after install centos and install bitnami xampp for linux and set it run on boot, the web server should active. and it does.

but after update and install key (rpm-gpg-key-centos-7) the apache and mysql can't run on boot time.

it never happend before. thanks for advice.

OS centos 7 64 bit (server with GUI)
lampp bitnami 5.6.8 64 bit

Comment: Can you manually start mysql and or apache?

Comment: yes it can started manually.

Comment: after i remove use yum erase fprintd like someone advice the problem still unsolved. the only way for now is centos 7 and lampp without anything until it solved

Comment: I have not used centos enough but sounds like to me it just replaced your startup and does not include mysql / apache. If you can manually start and all runs properly just re-add them to your startup script

Comment: it already set to run after boot, but it still not running. but ssh have no problem like httpd service